# Неявный вызов виртуальной клавиатуры

Tags: android, java

**Всем привет!**

Есть ли в `Android` способ вызвать виртуальную клавиатуру с помощью фокуса на одном `View`, предназначенном для ввода текста (`TextView`)? Т.е, сделать так, чтобы вместе с фокусом происходило появление клавиатуры для ввода текста?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то попробуйте добавить в xml элемент <requestFocus>, то бишь:

```
<TextView>
   <requestFocus/>
</TextView>
```

также можно вызывать программно метод View requestFocus().

Comment: попробуйте вызвать метод requestFocus или же юзайте InputMethodManager.

Comment: Добавьте в xml атрибуты android:focusable=false, android:focusableInTouchMode=false